# MySQL throwing duplicate entry on update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a non-key field on my table, but I keep getting duplicate primary key errors. For what I searched, it's an actual MySQL bug, but I'd like to know if there is a way around it, since so far I can´t update my table at all.

```
CREATE TABLE `AREA_FOLDER_PERMISSION` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FOLDER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `COMPANY_AREA_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CAN_READ` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `CAN_WRITE` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `CAN_PRINT` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `CAN_APPROVE` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `CAN_REVIEW` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `CAN_CREATE` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `FOLDER_ID_idx` (`FOLDER_ID`),
  KEY `COMPANY_AREA_ID_idx` (`COMPANY_AREA_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `COMPANY_AREA_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPANY_AREA_ID`) REFERENCES `COMPANY_AREA` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK2g92hsfhocnfsdr57fp7065mv` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPANY_AREA_ID`) REFERENCES `COMPANY_AREA` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKhisnf7elm60on0mjytiteio2a` FOREIGN KEY (`FOLDER_ID`) REFERENCES `FOLDER` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FOLDER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`FOLDER_ID`) REFERENCES `FOLDER` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1124828 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And the error is:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
UPDATE `sgidb`.`AREA_FOLDER_PERMISSION` SET `CAN_PRINT` = '1' WHERE (`ID` = '791063');

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '791063' for key 'id_UNIQUE'
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `sgidb`.`AREA_FOLDER_PERMISSION` SET `CAN_PRINT` = '1' WHERE (`ID` = '791063')
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: Why are you making your `bit` and `int` values `strings`? Might not have anything to do with the error.

Comment: Why the unnecessary `()` around `(\`ID\` = '791063')`? Also might not have anything to do with the errors

Comment: You also don't need your `id_UNIQUE` index if `ID` is your primary key

Comment: What are the details about this "actual MySQL bug"?

Comment: I don´t have a trigger on the table. And about the values being strings or the brackets, I just copied the error as MySQL gave it to me. The actual command I ran didn´t have those.

Comment: Also I think this is kind of the same bug I´m having
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68360

Comment: No, your case is completely different, since can_print is not part of a unique key, while in the "bug report" (which is not really a bug, mysql was designed that way) the updated field is part of a unique key and temporarily though, the query in the report does produce duplicate values. If your case was a bug, then it would be a serious one because there is no reason why that records would be a duplicate. So, I would rather leave that as the last resort option.

Comment: Have you considered that your id field may have duplicate ids? You can supress unique checks with unique_checks server variable temporarily.

Comment: I don't see how there could be duplicate ids, since the ID field is also the primary key.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you execute a single update statement, or is the error occurring in a script of sql statements that you are running?

Comment: The error happens with single and multiple updates

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67rMWLT7rnzVYnLpqVsdvY/0 I think the error is caused by something either in the data (perhaps data file is corrupted) or indeed there is a trigger somewhere.